# How to attach a library to a specific content type?

Tags: theming, 8

I wonder how to attach a library to a specific content type. .e.g News. I found the following code from a post and applied the "hook" to the "node" but no idea how to filter by content type. Any idea?

```
function fluffiness_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'fluffiness/cuddly-slider';
}
```

ref:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can check content type and add libraries like this:

```
function fluffiness_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  //check content type
  if ($node->getType() == 'article') {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'fluffiness/cuddly-slider'; 
  }
}
```

Comment: IMHO better use $node->bundle() directly instead of the getType() wrapper.