# Attach javascript library and settings to a node page

Tags: 8, display-suite, theming

Normally, to attach javascript (settings or just a library) to a Drupal 8 node type (page), you should use [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.2.x) and add it to the #attached array. ([example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226861/how-to-attach-a-library-to-a-specific-content-type))

Problem with the [display suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) is that the function is never reached. So you can't add the library and optionally the settings for that library to that node.

Although the [hook_preprocess_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8.2.x) function would suffice, I have the issue that I want to add it to a non-renderable field. So the field will never be displayed. I just need some javascript settings based on that field.

---

Example:

I have a node type: background_carousel_page
With a field: images (field type: image, multiple allowed)

I need to be able to add the images url to the settings of javascript to make the carousel displaying the images.

---

*So to summarize: I need a solution where I can add the library + settings to a specific node based on a field that's not being rendered.*

Comment: Have you tried adding it in the twig file for that field with `{{ attach_library(library) }}`?

Comment: But the inclusion and settings are dependant on a field. The use of the attach_library is only for inclusion of files, not settings? Correct me if I'm wrong ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try hook_entity_view or hook_node_view_alter:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view().
 */
function mymodule_entity_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {

  if ($entity->bundle() == 'background_carousel_page' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mylibrary';
  }

}
```

or

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter().
 */
function mymodule_node_view_alter(array &$build) {
  // @see \Drupal\Tests\embed\Functional\EmbedPreviewTest::testPreview
  $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mylibrary';
}
```

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer, as it is independent of the display suite module.
You can use the display suite function hook_ds_pre_render_alter and add it to the vars['#attached'] array there.